# Error occurrence while trying to validate form : unhandled exception:Null check operator used on null value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      try {
                        final newUser =
                            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email.text, password: password.text);
                        if (newUser != null) {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => DashboardScreen(),
                              ));
                        }

                        setState(() {});
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text(tSignup)),
```

Code for the form:

```
Form(
        child: Column(
          key: _formKey,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: fullName,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'Field is required.';
                return null;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text(tFullName),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline_rounded),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: tSecondaryColor),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: tSecondaryColor))),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: email,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'Field is required.';
                return null;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text(tEmail),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline_rounded),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: tSecondaryColor),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: tSecondaryColor))),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: phoneNo,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'Field is required.';
                return null;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text(tPhoneNo),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.numbers),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: tSecondaryColor),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: tSecondaryColor))),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: password,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'Field is required.';
                return null;
              },
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text(tPassword),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.security_rounded),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: tSecondaryColor),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: tSecondaryColor))),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      try {
                        final newUser =
                            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email.text, password: password.text);
                        if (newUser != null) {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => DashboardScreen(),
                              ));
                        }

                        setState(() {});
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text(tSignup)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: _formKey.currentState! check this is null or not, i believe this causing issue  in your code.

Comment: _formKey.currentState?.validate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use `_formKey` on your `Form` widget

```dart
Form(
  key:_formKey,
```

and follow this way

```dart
  onPressed: () async {
      final isValidate  = _formKey.currentState?.validate()??false; /// here I am providing false on null case.
      if (isValidate) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've passed the _formKey to the Column() not the Form() widget

```
    final GlobalKey<FormState>() _formKey = GlobalKey();
    body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column()
    ),
```